Compatibility of x8 2R RAM if the internal one is 16x 1R and vice versa
I am looking to buy an 8GB additional RAM for my laptop. The laptop currently has an 8GB DDR4 3200 MHz RAM as per the purchase specification sheet. In the additional slot, I wish to use this RAM.
However RAMs seem to come in two varieties x8 and x16. There are two different ranks as well 1R and 2R. I do not understand these terms, and can not figure out which one would be compatible with my machine.
I have checked that the specification sheet of my laptop mentions SODIMM, DDR4, and 3200 MHz, and the model linked above matches these specifications. The RAM is of Rank 1 as shown by the output of dmidecode -t -17.Is matching of these specifications enough to verify compatibility, or do the ranks 1R/2R and the x8/x16 thing also matter? I do not know whether the current inbuilt RAM is x8 or x16. Is there a way to figure it out?
The relevant part of sudo lshw output is
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
             product: KKRVFX-MIE
             vendor: AMD
             physical id: 0
             serial: A94EFE64
             slot: DIMM A
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM B

The laptop details are:
Model: Dell Vostro 3500
Processor: i5-1135G7
Motherboard: Dell Inc 0F5KMR
Graphics card: NV138 / Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
Some more output of sudo lshw:
    product: Vostro 3500 (0A24)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: 888KSH3
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.2.0 dmi-3.2.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Vostro sku=0A24 uuid=4c4c4544-0038-3810-804b-b8c04f534833
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0F5KMR
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /888KSH3/CNCMC001180731/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 1
          version: 1.28.0
          date: 12/15/2023
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 32MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.140.1
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 1230MHz
          capacity: 4200MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz

The output of dmidecode -t 17 is:
Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM A
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 3200 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 019800000000
    Serial Number: A94EFE64
    Asset Tag: 01212200
    Part Number: KKRVFX-MIE          
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 3200 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 2, Hex 0x98
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 8 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x1101, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM B
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown
    Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: None
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None


You can mix the number of ranks between the built-in and SODIMM slot memory. The only concern is about performance, whether both memory modules have to run at a lower speed than 3200 MT/s to be stable together.
